# Binding static resource and observable collection

Tags: wpf, binding, static, resources

I'm pretty new to WPF's data binding so try to keep things as simple as possible. :) I'm trying to bind a static resource and an observable collection together. They both are the same type.

Here's my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="DataBindingAdapterTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:lcu="http://schemas.org/">
    <Window.Resources>
        <lcu:DataPoints x:Key="jarppa">
            <lcu:DataPoint X="0" Y="5"/>
            <lcu:DataPoint X="3" Y="20"/>
            <lcu:DataPoint X="6" Y="10"/>
            <lcu:DataPoint X="6" Y="10"/>
        </lcu:DataPoints>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <lcu:chart x:Name="chart1"/>
        <lcu:BindingAdapter Name="bindingAdapter1" Chart="{Binding ElementName=chart1}">    
            <lcu:BindingAdapter.SeriesCollection>
                <lcu:ChartSeries Points="{Binding Source={StaticResource jarppa}}"/>
            </lcu:BindingAdapter.SeriesCollection>
        </lcu:BindingAdapter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ChartSeries.Points (class name DataPoints) is ObservableCollection< DataPoint> object and since "jarppa" is the same type I thought it would bind without trouble. Well, I was wrong...

I would like to bind "jarppa" so I could test the chart I'm working on in VS2010 designer. I.e. it would render the data points on screen. BindingAdapter provides binding functionality to my chart (a temporary solution). I think Path property should be used in this case since I'm using Source but how can I set the Path to point the whole list of DataPoint objects...?

How should I do this correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, never mind. Had a bug in my code elsewhere. Binding works now like it should. Thanks. :)

Comment: if the solution was related to your question, you can post it and accept it to help someone in the future or just flag to delete your  question if it's not related since it might not be of any help to someone landing on this to see "oh it was a bug elsewhere"

Comment: Could you please share the solution as I am also facing the same issue